# how do i compile a file with plugin stuff?

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, compilation

can you please tell me how to compile a folder in .jar?
I modified some source code of a plugin, now i've to try it, but as i said, i don't know how to compile it.

p.s.I use MacOsX

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile a Maven project:

- Invoke `mvn compile` on a shell in the project's folder or
- Select *Run* →  *Run as...* → *Maven build* on your project in Eclipse